# Conditional Probabilities on store data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes-classifier

I have data on store level purchases, Panel-level purchases and demographic information of loyalty cards.

In the store purchases information, the data consists of a product code which can be assigned to brands/products (Pepsi, Coke, Budweiser etc.) for many different products. Along with how many items of that product was sold that week and the price of each product.

In the Panel information, I have data on the product code, the number of items purchased in each store by that Panel ID and total number of $ spent on that product in that store.

In the demographic information I have data on each Panel ID:- how many people live in the household, panel_ID income, number of children, education etc.

I want to apply conditional probabilities on the product information, such as given that panel_ID bought product `A` what is the probability that they will buy product `B`.

However for just beer data I have 250 different brands and 300,000+ Panel_ID purchases.

I am thinking of applying Naive Bayes as a starting point, however what other Machine Learning methods would you suggest for such a problem?